# Нужна ли запятая между простыми предложениями после общей части?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*"На линкоре расположены маячки, не пытайтесь их найти — они хорошо замаскированы (,) и их много".*

Нужна ли запятая? Мне кажется, что здесь работает то же правило, что и с двоеточием, поэтому запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***На линкоре расположены маячки, не пытайтесь их найти — они хорошо замаскированы и их много.***

Действительно, запятая перед союзом *и* не нужна.

Вот правило у Розенталя:

https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=149#pp149

> Если два простых предложения с союзом *и* между ними соединены бессоюзной связью с предшествующим предложением, то они приравниваются к однородным придаточным частям сложноподчинённого предложения и запятая между ними не ставится.

**Ваше предложение целиком и полностью подпадает под вышеизложенное правило:**

Имеются два простых предложения с союзом *и* между ними (*они хорошо замаскированы и их много*), которые соединены бессоюзной связью с предшествующим предложением (вместо союза употреблено тире) и потому приравниваются к однородным придаточным частям сложноподчинённого предложения:

*...не пытайтесь их найти — они хорошо замаскированы и их много.* (БСП)

*...не пытайтесь их найти, потому что они хорошо замаскированы и их много.* (СПП)

> Мне кажется, что здесь работает то же правило, что и с двоеточием...

Конечно, вы абсолютно правы — здесь работает то же правило, что и с двоеточием, потому что в БСП двоеточие и тире могут ставиться на одних и тех же основаниях. Вот, в частности, отрывок правила из справочника Лопатина:

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

> В бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении пояснения, **причины, обоснования,** изъяснения допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике). Вот, в частности, примеры из произведений К. Паустовского: *Изредка в небе светилось голубоватое пятно — за тучками пробивалась луна, но тотчас гасла; Подснежники, наверное, уже прорастали в земле — их слабый травянистый запах просачивался сквозь снег; Слой облаков был очень тонок — сквозь него просвечивало солнце; На молу погасили огни — теплоход ушел; Татьяна Андреевна вздрагивала от сырости — после теплой каюты на палубе было свежо; Паханов крепко держал капитана за локоть — капитан был еще слаб после ранения; Ей хотелось заплакать — лом даже через варежки леденил руки; В армию меня тоже не берут — сердце заштопанное; Однажды зимой вышел я и слышу — стонет кто-то за оградой.*
> Примеры из произведений современных авторов и из периодической печати: *Думать мне пришлось недолго — дверь распахнулась, и я увидел Чапаева (Пелев.); В дом попасть никто не мог — двери и окна были закрыты (газ.); Доски гнулись и ходили ходуном под его ботинками — он был тяжелым, а пол старым (Уст.); Мы ее Барбариска звали — она вечно всех детей карамелью угощала... (Улиц.). То же при глаголах, требующих пояснения: Вскинул голову — у порога стоит Мария (Шукш.); А помню — в сугробах тонули дворы (Сн.); Казалось мне — с любовью строгой она глядит из-под бровей (Лис); Она испуганно осмотрелась — никого (Расп.); Ольга посмотрела вперед — ничего особенного.. .(Уст.).*

Вообще говоря, не нужно пугаться, если в предложении тире употреблено там, где, казалось бы, должно стоять двоеточие. Вот что по этому поводу пишет сам Розенталь:

https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=189#pp189

> В заключение можно указать, что в «конкурентной борьбе» двоеточия с тире «победителем» нередко выходит тире. Это явление отмечается многими исследователями, которые считают, что «в целом тире — знак более свободный, заходящий и во владения двоеточия»[36] и что «выявляется тенденция к вытеснению в ряде случаев двоеточия знаком тире»[37]. Объяснить это можно особым статусом тире среди других знаков препинания: «В настоящее время тире очень употребительный и многофункциональный знак препинания. Он выполняет как грамматические (чисто синтаксические), так и эмоционально-экспрессивные функции; особенно широко используется он в последнем качестве в художественной литературе»[38]

Answer (score 1):

Я бы это предложение записала бы так:

(1) На линкоре расположены маячки, (2) но не пытайтесь их обнаружить — (3) они хорошо замаскированы и (4) их много.

Предложения (3) и (4) объединены союзом И, так как они оба относятся к предложению (2). Запятая в этом случае не ставится.